# Как сделать чтобы бот отвечал определённым людям?

Tags: python, telebot

У меня есть чат в телеграмме и бот в нём на pyhton telebot.

Есть такая команда как /infos, хочу чтобы бот отвечал на эту команду только админу с adminid = например 1234567

Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Проверять по chat_id, у каждого пользователя телеграмма он уникальный. У каждого сообщения возвращаться message, в нем есть chat_id, что бы получить его можно написать специальному боту https://t.me/userinfobot для получения chat id.
Код как сделать проверку на chat_id пользователя:

```
if message.chat.id == xxxxxxx:
       #Тут выполняем код
else:
       #Тут если пользователь не xxxxxxx chat_id
```

Comment: Что за бред, у каждого юзера уникальный только юзер айди, а не чат айди. `message.from_user.id`

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут все просто тебе просто нужно проверить id юзера на соответсвие
Вот пример

```
bot = telebot.TeleBot('твой апи')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['infos'])
def send_message_user(message):
    if message.from_user.id == 'id юзера':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Hello')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'error')
```

лучше занеси определенный id в переменную либо список вот и все надеюсь мой ответ помог тебе!